# java design pattern to use

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

This could be a duplicate question, but I'm learning different patterns and trying to implement them in my code.

I'm trying to understand which pattern to use in this example. I'm thinking of using the factory pattern, but this confuses me for the given scenario. 
I have an `interface` `Shape` and implementation classes `Rectangle` and `Square`

The `Rectangle` & `Square` classes implement all the methods in the `Shape` interface.
Now, I have a couple of get and set methods in the `Square` class.
If I use the factory pattern this way, I get exceptions

```
public class Square implements Shape {  
   public String getSomeField() {
     return
   }
   public void setSomeField() {
      //set something
   }
}

public class ShapeFactory {
   public static Shape getShape(String shape) {
      if(shape.equals("rectangle") {
         return new Rectangle();
      } else {
         return new Square();
      }
   }    
}
```

I instantiate my Square class like this:
`Shape square = ShapeFactory.getShape("square");`

Since i have methods `setSomeField()` and `getSomeField()`, i get exceptions

**Questions**:

1. Do I need to use factory pattern here or any other pattern?
2. Do I have to instantiate like this: `Square square = (Square)ShapeFactory.getShape("square");`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by introducing a factory here. Is there a reason why you can't instantiate the classes directly?

Comment: Because `getShape` is returning a `Shape`, the compiler can't guarantee that the result is a `Square`. You'd need to cast it, or use generics; but in this case, I believe casting would be easier.

Comment: @Ray i'm doing it directly now, but I want to know which is the right approach. Do it directly or use a design pattern

Comment: @user525146 Design Patterns are used to solve a particular problem. You shouldn't implement them, because you want to use a pattern; rather you should apply a pattern, because you have run into a particular issue. From your question, I don't see the need for applying this particular pattern at all.

Comment: Your issue could currently be solved just with [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: What is your exception?

Comment: The code you're showing wouldn't compile, since getSomeField doesn't return anything. Can you show the Shape interface, the code that invokes the getShape method and most importantly a compilable version of Square and / or Rectangle? Note that getSomeField() would return a null pointer exception if you never set the field.

Comment: Btw, the factory method is perfectly correct. It avoids having to maintain the code which calls getShape in the invoking class, and avoids the need to cast, which is the whole point. It might be overkill in a very simple program, but this is presumably a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure you ***need*** to use the factory pattern here since your example is very simple, but you certainly can.
   Since your objects are very simple, you could just as well used `Shape s = new Square();` in your code. The factory pattern is best suited in situations in which the creation of the objects is complex, or if the factory needs to know that an object was created. For example if the ShapeFactory had to know how many Shapes of different types were created.
2. No. I don't know what exception you're getting, but the following code works for me:

   ```
   public class Main {

       public interface Shape {
           public String getName();
       }

       public static class Square implements Shape {

           @Override
           public String getName() {
               return "I'm a Square";
           }
       }

       public static class Rectangle implements Shape {
           @Override
           public String getName() {
               return "I'm a Rectangle";
           }
       }

       public static class ShapeFactory {
           public Shape getShape(String shape) {
               if (shape.equals("rectangle")) {
                   return new Rectangle();
               } else {
                   return new Square();
               }
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           ShapeFactory sf = new ShapeFactory();
           System.out.println(sf.getShape("rectangle").getName());
           System.out.println(sf.getShape("something else").getName());
       }
   }
   ```

It prints:

```
I'm a Rectangle
I'm a Square
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends from your design. Any of the main [Creational](http://www.javatpoint.com/creational-design-patterns) patterns - can do the job according to your case needs. If you don't need to get a canned object every time, then [Builder](http://www.javatpoint.com/builder-design-pattern) will give you a fluent way to construct your `Shape` objects. Looking at your code (and assuming you actually may end up with having many parameters) like

```
 public String getSomeField();
 public void setSomeField();
```

this is an option to be considered. A simple example how Builder will provide better control over construction process:

```
 public Rectangle getRectangle() {
    return new
            Rectangle.RectangleBuilder()
            .length(60)
            .width(30)                
            .build();
}
```